# Ошибка при вводе буквы

Tags: python

```
congratulation = "Поздравляю вы угадали,\
возьмите пирожок с полки: "
number = 100
running = True

while running:
    task = int(input("Угадайте целое число: ") )

    if task == number:
        print(congratulation)
        running = False

    elif task < number:
            print("Хорошая попытка, но нужное число немого больше")


    else:
        print("Хорошая попытка, но нужное число немного меньше")

input()
```

Если вводить буквы или не вводить ничего, появляется ошибка. Как её исправить (я зелёный новичок :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

congratulation = "Поздравляю вы угадали, " \
                 "возьмите пирожок с полки: "
number = randint(0, 100)
running = True

while running:
    print("Угадайте целое число:", end='')
    input_is_number = False
    task = 0    # чтобы избежать ошибки, если удалишь 'if input_is_number'
                # потому что в try при вводе буквы будет ошибка
                # а в except мы task не объявляли
    try:  # блок кода в котором может произойти ошибка
        # Буквы нельзя превратить в числа, будет ошибка ValueError
        task = int(input())
        input_is_number = True
    except ValueError:  # блок кода, который выполниться в случае ошибки
        print('Вы ввели не число')

    if input_is_number:
        # Если пользователь ввел число
        if task == number:
            print(congratulation)
            running = False

        elif task < number:
            print("Хорошая попытка, но нужное число немого больше")
        else:
            print("Хорошая попытка, но нужное число немного меньше")

input()
print('Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow!')
```

Comment: Спасибо, хотя пока в коде не всё понятно

Comment: Я программу немного улучшил, теперь она сама загадывает число, а ты его угадываешь. Гугли, пробуй, заходи)